# JavaScript prompt input to <td> element

Tags: javascript, html

JAVASCRIPT Below - The script below prompts the user to type in their first name and then stores that name in the variable "person." Variable "x" is supposed to be the first element in the table.

```
<script>
    function getName()
    {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your first name", "Johnny");
        var x = getElementById('personName');
        x.value = person;
    }
</script>
```

HTML Below - The first element in the table row is what should change when the user types in their name. But I cannot seem to get the element to change it's value.

```
<body onload="getName()>
    <table id="statsTable" border="1px" class="stats">
        <tr>
            <td id="personName">Person</td>
            <td>Computer</td>
            <td>Winner</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You have forgotten to close the double quote here:

```
<body onload="getName()>
```

2- You have forgotten to call getElementById on any object. You can fix it as follows:

```
var x = document.getElementById('personName');
```

3- Instead of value, you should use innerHTML:

```
x.innerHTML = person;
```

Or

```
x.textContent = person;
```

So the whole code should be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="getName()">
    <table id="statsTable" border="1px" class="stats">
        <tr>
            <td id="personName">Person</td>
            <td>Computer</td>
            <td>Winner</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    function getName()
    {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your first name", "Johnny");
        var x = document.getElementById('personName');
        x.innerHTML = person;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `x.value = person;` to `x.innerText = person`.

Comment: `innerText` is not portable, use `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
x.innerText = person;
```

instead of x.value as the value will change an attribute rather then the text of the

Answer (score 0):

The last line in the function `getName()` has errors. Change it to:

```
x.innerText = document.getElementById('personName');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.value` is used to set the value of an input element. To set the content of a `<td>`, use `.textContent`.

Also, the name of the function to get the element is `document.getElementById()`.

```js
function getName() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your first name", "Johnny");
  var x = document.getElementById('personName');
  x.textContent = person;
}

getName();
```

```html
<table id="statsTable" border="1px" class="stats">
  <tr>
    <td id="personName">Person</td>
    <td>Computer</td>
    <td>Winner</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You! Helps a lot, still new to DOM.